# XSIM and crossrefs

Tags: ref, xsim, crossreftools

I looked at the template `xsim_crossref.tex` (in the XSIM documentation) to create hyperlinks between statements and solutions.

It works fine but now I would like to hide the empty references (exercises with no solution). As suggested in the first comment, this can be done with the conditional test `\IfExistSolutionTF`, but the first exercise with no solution is empty.

1. How can I fix it ?
2. Would it be possible to have just one solution environment ? *i.e.* to delete `solprob` and just use `sol` in the sequel.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum,hyperref}
\usepackage[blank,clear-aux]{xsim}

\DeclareExerciseHeadingTemplate{custom}{\XSIMtranslate{default-heading}}
%
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{custom}
  {%
    \IfExistSolutionTF
        {%
            \IfInsideSolutionTF
              {%
              \label{sol:\ExerciseID}}
              {%
              \label{ex:\ExerciseID}}
         }{}%
    \IfInsideSolutionTF
        {%
            {\color{green}\bfseries\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}~(\GetExerciseParameter{exercise-name}%
                ~\GetExerciseProperty{counter})}%
        }
        {%
            {\color{orange}\bfseries\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}~{\color{black}\bfseries\itshape\GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{\PropertyValue}}%
        }
    \IfExistSolutionTF
        {%
        \IfInsideSolutionTF
             {%
              {\color{gray}\footnotesize{(Énoncé~:~\pageref{ex:\ExerciseID})}~}%
             }
             {%
             {\color{gray}\footnotesize{\big(\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseParameter{solution-name}}~:~\pageref{sol:\ExerciseID}\big)}~}
             }%
         }%
         {}%
  }{}

% Traductions
\DeclareExerciseTranslations{problem}{
    Fallback = problème ,
    English  = problem ,
    French   = problème ,
}
\DeclareExerciseTranslations{problems}{
    Fallback = problèmes ,
    English  = problems ,
    French   = problèmes ,
}
\DeclareExerciseType{exercice}{
    exercise-env      = exo ,
    solution-env      = sol ,
    exercise-name     = \XSIMtranslate{exercise} ,
    exercises-name    = \XSIMtranslate{exercises} ,
    solution-name     = \XSIMtranslate{solution} ,
    solutions-name    = \XSIMtranslate{solutions} ,
    exercise-template = custom ,
    solution-template = custom ,
    exercise-heading  = custom ,
    solution-heading  = custom
}
\DeclareExerciseType{probleme}{
    exercise-env      = prob ,
    solution-env      = solprob ,
    exercise-name     = \XSIMtranslate{problem} ,
    exercises-name    = \XSIMtranslate{problems} ,
    solution-name     = \XSIMtranslate{solution} ,
    solutions-name    = \XSIMtranslate{solutions} ,
    exercise-template = custom ,
    solution-template = custom ,
    exercise-heading  = custom ,
    solution-heading  = custom
}
%
\xsimsetup{
    print-solutions/headings-template = custom ,
    print-solutions/headings = false ,
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

\begin{exo}
ABCDE
\end{exo}

\begin{exo}
\lipsum[1]
\end{exo}
\begin{sol}
\lipsum[1]
\end{sol}

%
\begin{prob}[subtitle={A problem but "solprob" instead of "sol" is mandatory}]
\lipsum[1]  
\end{prob}
%
\begin{solprob}
\lipsum[1]  
\end{solprob}


\printsolutions*

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should be able to check for an existing solution in the template with `\IfExistSolutionTF`

Comment: Thanks ! I'm going to try.

Comment: I have edited my question taking into account the first comment, but now an exercise having no solution is printed empty.

Comment: Your code compiles with errors. If I exchange remove the unnecessary `\XSIMmixedcase` from `\XSIMmixedcase{Énoncé}`, i.e. only use `Énoncé` and add the missing third argument to `\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate` then the code compiles without errors and the first exercise is not empty

Comment: I have deleted all the auxiliary files and bodies of exercises/answers. The code compiles without errors, but the first exercise is still empty (whereas the body file is not ... ). Do you think that the code (updated) in the question is now correct?

Comment: There is a bug in `\xsim_if_exist:nnnTF`. The body appears if you use `xsim` with the `no-files` option…

Comment: OK, thank you. Could we expect a fix in a future release ? Since I need verbatim material in exercises and answers, I can't deal with the `no-files` option.

Comment: Yes, I'll update xsim in the next few days or weeks

Comment: I just tested with the latest version of XSIM: the solution body is now missing, and only contains the word `solution`. I observe the same with the template `xsim_crossref.tex` supplied with the package.

Comment: use `\usepackage[use-files]{xsim}` until this is fixed (in v0.20c), cf. https://github.com/cgnieder/xsim/issues/80

Comment: Everything works, thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments of cgnieder, the following code does finally the trick.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum,hyperref}
\usepackage[use-files,blank,clear-aux]{xsim}
%
\DeclareExerciseHeadingTemplate{custom}{\XSIMtranslate{default-heading}}
%
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{custom}
  {%
    \IfExistSolutionTF
        {%
            \IfInsideSolutionTF
              {%
              \label{sol:\ExerciseID}
              }
              {%
              \label{ex:\ExerciseID}
              }
         }{}%
    \IfInsideSolutionTF
        {%
            {\color{green}\bfseries\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}~(\GetExerciseParameter{exercise-name}%
                ~\GetExerciseProperty{counter})}%
        }
        {%
            {\color{orange}\bfseries\XSIMmixedcase{\GetExerciseName}~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}~{\color{black}\bfseries\itshape\GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{\PropertyValue}}%
        }
    \IfExistSolutionTF
        {%
        \IfInsideSolutionTF
             {%
              {\color{gray}\footnotesize{\big(Énoncé:\pageref{ex:\ExerciseID}\big)}~}%
             }
             {%
             {\color{gray}\footnotesize{\big(Solution:\pageref{sol:\ExerciseID}\big)}~}
             }%
         }%
         {}%
  }{}

% Traductions
\DeclareExerciseTranslations{problem}{
    Fallback = problème ,
    English  = problem ,
    French   = problème ,
}
\DeclareExerciseTranslations{problems}{
    Fallback = problèmes ,
    English  = problems ,
    French   = problèmes ,
}
\DeclareExerciseType{exercice}{
    exercise-env      = exo ,
    solution-env      = sol ,
    exercise-name     = \XSIMtranslate{exercise} ,
    exercises-name    = \XSIMtranslate{exercises} ,
    solution-name     = \XSIMtranslate{solution} ,
    solutions-name    = \XSIMtranslate{solutions} ,
    exercise-template = custom ,
    solution-template = custom ,
    exercise-heading  = custom ,
    solution-heading  = custom
}
\DeclareExerciseType{probleme}{
    exercise-env      = prob ,
    solution-env      = solprob ,
    exercise-name     = \XSIMtranslate{problem} ,
    exercises-name    = \XSIMtranslate{problems} ,
    solution-name     = \XSIMtranslate{solution} ,
    solutions-name    = \XSIMtranslate{solutions} ,
    exercise-template = custom ,
    solution-template = custom ,
    exercise-heading  = custom ,
    solution-heading  = custom
}
%
\xsimsetup{
    print-solutions/headings-template = custom ,
    print-solutions/headings = false ,
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}

\begin{exo}
ABCDE
\end{exo}

\begin{exo}
\lipsum[1]
\end{exo}
\begin{sol}
\lipsum[1]
\end{sol}

%
\begin{prob}
\lipsum[1]  
\end{prob}
%
\begin{solprob}
\lipsum[1]  
\end{solprob}


\printsolutions*

\end{document}
```